# Ajax Json is posting null to controller action method

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have a razor view with the following AJAX Jquery to post the UserData object to the controller. It calls the action method but the value in the parameter when debugging in the controller is null. I have looked on the net and stackoverflow at similar questions but still cannot see what the following code is missing:

In my razor view:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var UserData = {"name":"test"}

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Send/',
            data : JSON.stringify(UserData),
            type: 'POST',
            traditional: true,
            contentType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#message').html("json data was sent to controller");
            }
        });
    })});
```

And in my Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Send(UserData userdata)
{
    return Json(new { status = true });
}

public class UserData
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

The UserData object matches the object I am sending in the AJAX post but the value of the parameter in the controller action method is null.

What else do I need to add to make the data come through to the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your contentType to `'application/json'`. This tells ASP.NET MVC to deserialize the request body as JSON and it will fix the null value on your controller.

Your ajax code will look something similar to this:

```
var UserData = {"name":"test"}

$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/Send/',
    data : JSON.stringify(UserData),
    type: 'POST',
    traditional: true,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data) {
        $('#message').html("json data was sent to controller");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. I thought I had tried 'application/json' and a few other content types. Is it possible to use this method of posting data within a @Html.BeginForm to submit form values as well or must I create a javascript object with the form values and then post that as the data as in the example above with ajax?

Comment: No problem! With form data, you can simply call `$('#yourForm').serialize()` and not need to explicitly send the content type with the request. By default, jQuery sends `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as the content type for an ajax request if none is specified. Just make sure that your form fields have the correct names and ASP.NET MVC will be able to read the request data.